# Settings to Windows Firewall to allow Docker for Windows to share drive

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

Windows Firewall is blocking my attempt to allows Docker for Windows to share C: on windows 10 machine.

Works fine when Windows Firewall off. When its on I get

> A firewall is blocking file Sharing between Windows and the
>   containers. See documentation for more info.

The documentation says

> You do not need to open port 445 on any other network. By default,
>   allow connections to 10.0.75.1 port 445 (the Windows host) from
>   10.0.75.2 (the virtual machine).

I am "googled out" on trying to find how to do that - can someone advise?

Comment: Cisco AnyConnect VPN was blocking this for me, after exiting the VPN, it worked.

Comment: I have Cisco blocking me but I NEEED to be on the VPN as well as have Docker sharing... Any ideas?

Comment: I followed this for Norton Firewall and it worked perfectly https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45159006/what-to-change-in-norton-to-allow-docker-to-share-drive-d

Comment: See below post that answers this question https://superuser.com/questions/1470821/how-to-access-local-remote-docker-container-from-another-machine-on-local-remote

Comment: @NicolasIrisarri: I solved the same problem (Need to use both of them at the same time). The solution is to use a different subnet than the one secured by AnyConnect. See my answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58406873/9064636

Comment: The Edge version of Docker for Windows since 2.1.5.0 has a new implementation of file sharing without requiring firewall modifications: https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/edge-release-notes/ You can download the edge version: https://download.docker.com/win/edge/Docker%20Desktop%20Installer.exe

Answer (score 155):

You don't actually need to share the C drive but only reinstall (or potentially even uncheck - click OK - then check) the File and Print sharing service on the Hyper-V virtual network card.
[See this article.](https://blog.olandese.nl/2017/05/03/solve-docker-for-windows-error-a-firewall-is-blocking-file-sharing-between-windows-and-the-containers/)

Also if there are restrictions on your network profiles (i.e. public), consider changing the default "unidentified network" for the "vEthernet (DockerNAT)" card to private via this PowerShell command before doing the above:

```
Set-NetConnectionProfile -interfacealias "vEthernet (DockerNAT)" -NetworkCategory Private
```

Comment: I had to close Docker for Windows and restart it after running the above Powershell command. You can run `Get-NetConnectionProfile` to ensure that the `DockerNAT` network is in the `Private` category

Comment: The link to https://blog.olandese.nl/2017/05/03/solve-docker-for-windows-error-a-firewall-is-blocking-file-sharing-between-windows-and-the-containers/ solved my problem. Many thanks!

Comment: None of these worked for me so I tried: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47837191/1895627

Comment: This command solves it for me, but unfortunately due to something in my org. group policy it gets reset every time I reboot the machine which is super annoying.

Comment: I found this approach is more convenient, though like @RobertNoack, I have to re-do it every time after reboot.

Comment: This worked for me, ditto on the having to redo it after each reboot, seems like I have the group policy issue as well

Comment: I cannot uninstall that, I get error `0x80071779`, I tried to disable -> enable. Also firewall disabled... I also tried to set to private, still not working, any ideas?

Comment: Uninstalling/Installing File Sharing did not resolve the issue but after running the "Set-NetConnectionProfile..." command I was able to share drives with Docker.

Comment: This actually worked for me and it's not hard.  Just run Powershell as an administrator, and execute the command in this answer: `Set-NetConnectionProfile -interfacealias "vEthernet (DockerNAT)" -NetworkCategory Private`.  (I did not need to quit Docker, and it worked.)  Be sure to return to `Docker Settings -> Shared Drives`, and `reset credentials` - and then place a checkmark in the desired drive.  Attempt to create a Docker container with volume mounting now - it worked for me - no more firewall issue.  Why, oh why, does Docker not simply include these instructions for Docker for Windows?

Comment: deinstall File and Print sharing service: `Disable-NetAdapterBinding -Name "vEthernet (DockerNAT)" -ComponentID ms_server`

Comment: `Set-NetConnectionProfile` worked for me, i've tried in PowerShell Core first which didn't work very well, and with PowerShell 5 which works very well.

Comment: None of this worked for me; it was because SMB1 was disabled on my laptop by IT ... enable it and all fine again. Docker needs to move away from SMB1 really.

Comment: It is not anymore possible to uninstall file and printer sharing using the UI. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4340181/error-0x80071779-when-removing-client-for-microsoft-networks @MarcelD-B comment worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 72):

Ok, so after running in the same issue,
I have found a Solution.

This is what I did:

---

Step 1:
Open ESET. Then click on **Setup**

[image: click setup]

Step 2:
Click on **Network protection**

[image: click network protection]

Step 3:
Click on **Troubleshooting wizard**

[image: click troubleshooting wizard]

Step 4:
Find the Communication **10.0.75.2** (Default docker IP setting)
*Just check what the IP Range is defined inside your docker settings. Then look for for the IP which resides in that range.*

[image: find the connection]

Step 5:
Click on the **Unblock** button, then you should receive this screen.

[image: click unblock]

This solved the issue for myself.

You can then go to the Rules and check the rule that was added.

---

*PS: This is my first post, sorry for any incorrect procedures.*

Comment: This post was extremely useful for me, because when adding the rules like explained in the docs, the IP addresses mentioned where different. Goed bezig!

Comment: For all of the ESET users out there, **this** is the solution, thank you!

Comment: An excellent contribution by Franche Van Den Berg, thanks. This is indeed the solution for ESET users, and a very elegant one.

Comment: For ESET ensure that the docker network is in the Trusted Zone

Comment: This exact solution worked for me flawlessly. Thank You!

Answer (score 65):

Only this solution helps me:

- Go to Hyper-V Manager -> Virtual Switch Manager -> DockerNAT -> Connection Type: change from internal to private, apply, change back to internal, apply
- Restart MobyLinuxVM
- Restart Docker
- Set Docker network profile to 'Private'. Run command in PowerShell as admin
  `Set-NetConnectionProfile -interfacealias "vEthernet (DockerNAT)" -NetworkCategory Private`
- Reset File and Printer Sharing for Microsoft Networks on DockerNAT connection
- Go to Docker -> Settings -> Shared Drives and share C:

Comment: worth metioning that `Set-NetConnectionProfile` is to be ran in PowerShell as admin and not normal Cmd. It works fine for me but the Ethernet adapter is still `unidentified network`

Comment: carpet bombing FTW. None of the other solutions worked. Thanks.

Comment: This worked 100%. None of the other options worked this time and the ultimate solution was to set the network to Private.

Comment: Thanks man! You saved my day. That is only one work way to fix this damn bug.

Comment: Worked for me. Most of the other solution did not. ensure you follow ALL steps. I missed the "Set Docker network profile to 'Private' Set-NetConnectionProfile -interfacealias "vEthernet (DockerNAT)" -NetworkCategory Private" step at my own peril.

Comment: I just had to do the first step for it to work, thanks.

Comment: It works!!! But on the point "Restart docker" you have to exit docker, and then start it again, not simply apply changes on its settings windows...

Comment: This worked!!! Although, I think I only needed the internal to private back to internal and restart of Docker steps.

Comment: It works, but as @DarkMukke said, I had to identify it with **unidentified network**, no pum ;)

Comment: This helped me solve a slightly different issue where I couldn't get a container to start on a specific port even though it was listed as unused by docker and by windows.

Comment: For those who want to know what "Reset File and Printer Sharing for Microsoft Networks on DockerNAT connection" means. Adopting from another popular answer,in my case, it meant to disable this service in the "vEthernet (DockerNAT)" network adapter and then enabling it again. I was not able to and, apparently did not need to uninstall/reinstall that service. Just disable->click ok->open properties again->enable->click ok.

Answer (score 60):

My solution was to disconnect from the VPN; that was causing the issue

Comment: I also solved the issue after disconnecting from my VPN, which of course, I didn't try until exhausting all other possibilities.  *sigh*

Comment: I was searching for a half of the day and just needed to disconnect from the VPN.. Thanks!

Comment: Simple solution..Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! I forgot my VPN Client that automatically starts at windows boot.

Comment: Thank you! I followed different instruction with no success, but once disconnected from VPN, it worked!!!

Answer (score 28):

I was not using any third party firewalls when running into this error. I was convinced it was a Windows Firewall issue, though disabling Windows Firewall did not work for me. I finally found this blog post after much research: [Docker on windows 10 error: A firewall is blocking file Sharing ...](http://blog.medhat.ca/2017/01/docker-on-windows-10-error-firewall-is.html)

It ended up **NOT** having to do with the built in Windows Firewall.

> **The Fix**
>
> 1. **Uncheck** *File and Printer Sharing for Microsoft Networks* from the **vEthernet (DockerNAT)** network adapter (you can find the connection in the Windows *Network and Sharing Center*).
> 2. **Recheck** it and make sure it is enabled.

Comment: Worked for me perfectly, Thanks!

Comment: Apparently this worked for me as well. I checked the Windows Firewall and I already had the correct rule, probably pre-installed by docker itself.

Comment: Would be nice to know why this works and what that actual root cause of the issue is. Seems to happen frequently.

Comment: Problem is you have to do it again after the system reboot

Comment: @AFD, interesting, I do not have that problem.

Answer (score 22):

My C drive stopped being shared with Docker after a recent Windows 10 update. I was getting the same problem saying it was blocked by the Windows firewall when attempting to reshare it.

Looking through the above solutions, I found something that worked for me that is simpler than anything else I saw on this page. In ***Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Network and Sharing Center***, on the ***vEthernet (DockerNAT)*** connection, I unchecked the property ***File and Printer Sharing for Microsoft Networks*** and saved the setting. Then I checked the property again to reenable it and saved it again.

At this point, I was able to reshare the C drive in Docker settings. I have no idea why this worked but it was not a firewall problem, which already have an entry for DockerSmbMount.

Comment: WOW this is a disappointing bug.. I searched all day long thank you

Comment: this almost worked. i don't get the firewall message but the checkbox doesnt remain ticked!

Answer (score 17):

I had this problem with Kaspersky; turning off Kaspersky worked, so I knew it was the firewall. In my case, Kaspersky was already blocking port 445 for some reason. I had to go to Packet Rules for the Firewall, Local Services (TCP) and remove 445 from the list of blocks ports.

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

Comment: Worked for me! But the UI looked different in Kaspersky ES 10. It can be found like this: Settings tab > Select "Firewall" on the left side > click button "Network packet rules" > Select "TCP connection local" > Select Edit at the top

Comment: Instead of removing 445 from the list, changed 'Action' from 'Blocked' to 'By Application Rules' and it worked for me. So I guess removing 445 from 'Local Services (TCP)' and creating a new rule 'Docker SMB Mount' with action 'By Application Rules' should also work.

Comment: This one worked for me. I had to pause Kaspersky and then try enable the shared drive on Docker for Windows.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the solution for Kaspersky. It worked for me.

Comment: I had the same problem and followed https://matthewhorne.me/docker-drive-sharing-seems-blocked-firewall-kaspersky/

Answer (score 11):

For Windows 10 machines on domain networks, when creating the Hyper-V virtual Ethernet adapter, it gets categorized as a public network. You have to change it to a private network to allow the more relaxed Windows Firewall rules, and therefore allow file sharing.

Run the following command in PowerShell:

```
Set-NetConnectionProfile -interfacealias "vEthernet (DockerNAT)" -NetworkCategory Private
```

Change the name in quotes if your machine's virtual Hyper-V network connection is called something else.

Comment: Worked like a charm for me. Ran the command in a Powershell 6 session on a Windows 10 v10.0.17763 build 17763, Docker v18.09.2 build 6247962, and running Norton Security Suite.

Answer (score 9):

My problem was Cisco Anyconnect VPN interfered with internal docker networking

to fix this go to:
Cisco Anyconnect Settings > Preferences > 
check `Allow local (LAN) access when using VPN`

Comment: This worked for me when the File Print Sharing suggestions didn't. Anyconnect `Allow local (LAN) access when using VPN` was already checked so I unchecked it, disconnected, rechecked the option and reconnected to the VPN. Docker for Windows then applied the drive share as desired.

Comment: Didn't work for me, I had to disconnect Cisco AnyConnect to share drives. Any ideas?

Comment: Apparently our corporate network warriors have secured 0.0.0.0/0, so I'm out of luck :-(

Answer (score 8):

As stated in one other answer Docker doesn't play nice with a VPN.
If you're using Nordvpn you have to disable **"Invisibility on LAN"** and probably **"Internet Kill Switch"**.

If you've done so it should work even with the VPN active.

[image: NordVPN Client]

Comment: Thank you! This solved it for me. I was stuck for 2 weeks!

Comment: Thank you so much! Several hours down the drain of playing around with network settings, this is the only thing that worked for me!

Answer (score 6):

That depends on what firewall do you have installed. In my case I do have disabled the built-in Windows Firewall and I am using ESET Smart Security so my rules looks like:

- Create a rule for **IN** connection since you should allow Docker to connect to your host and set it to **Allow**

[image]

- Setup the port properly as explained in docs meaning `445`:

[image]

- Setup the remote IP address:

[image]

Maybe this is not the answer since it's not related to Windows Firewall but could give you a clue in what to do.

Comment: Thanks Reynier - I followed what you show as best I could in the Windows Firewall equivalent. 
- General tab = "Enabled"
- Protocols and Ports tab = TCP protocol and local port = 445
- Scope tab = Remote ip = 10.0.75.2
But got same error message. Allowed all ports and IP addresses - same result. Another rule is taking precedence?

Comment: Will be better if you add some screenshots of what you've because I hate Windows Firewall and never deal with it before ...

Comment: how can you select the "System" application?

Comment: No need to add the "System" application but you need to Make sure that the DockerNAT network is trusted in Known Networks with IP range 10.0.75.1/24

Comment: We are not using ESET :/

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I **disabled** "Block TCP 445" on ***Windows Defender Firewall with Advanced Security*** and it worked. Then **enabled** it again after setting **shared drives** on Docker.

[image: setting of Block TCP 445]

[image: setting of Shared drives]

Comment: I just realized I personally added this firewall rule back when NSA hacking tools got leaked. Thanks!

Comment: confirmed , adding this 445 stuff , worked https://i.imgur.com/vTNfORA.jpg

Answer (score 4):

None of the above worked for me.

What finally did the trick was opening the properties of the "vEthernet (DockerNAT)" network and ticking the box "Hyper-V Extensible Virtual Switch" at the bottom of the list under the "Networking" tab.

Not sure if this is the actual fix or whether it just somehow reset the network adapter for me... but it worked!

Answer (score 4):

Seem like many having this issue when running Cisco AnyConnect. I got the same problem and here is how I solved:

The cause: The subnet being used by Docker is in the list of *Secured Routes* managed by Cisco AnyConnect (I believe this list is managed by your VPN's admin).

The solution: Change the subnet used by Docker to not overlap with the list being managed by AnyConnect.

For example, in my case, I changed from 10.0.75.0 (which was overlapped with 10.0.0.0/8) to 172.31.0.0/28.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and tried all the fixes - and it turned out that more than one was necessary:

- Add a firewall rule (Norton Security for me)
- Make the network private
- Share the drive

I've written a full explanation at http://kajabity.com/2017/08/unblock-docker-for-windows-firewall-issues-with-host-volumes/

Comment: “While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.”

Comment: Key here for me was making the docker network private.

Answer (score 3):

My G drive stopped being shared with Docker after a recent Windows 10 update. I was getting the same problem saying it was blocked by the Windows firewall when attempting to reshare it.

Then I had tried to solve this issues by couple of suggestion but i cant resolve that issue after that I have tried to Reset credentials below of Shared Drives and my issue was solved.

So If you want then you can try to do this-

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Everything everyone posted DID NOT WORK for me.

THIS DID.

I installed the EDGE release. I then went to WINDOWS DEFENDER and disabled the firewall for DOCKER NAT. (not my actual ethernet adapter, just the docker nat)

Once I disabled windows defender/firewall THAT way it worked fine.

ugh. really hopes that helps some of you!

Comment: disabling firewall for specific connection (dockerNat) helped. Thank you very much!

Comment: Please explain how exactly did you disable Windows Defender firewall for specific network adapter/connection?

Answer (score 3):

Even after ensuring that the inbound firewall rule is set up properly and even after uninstalling and reinstalling the **File and Printing Sharing Service** it didn't work for me.

**Solution:** on top of that I also had to do a third thing. I had to deactivate the checkbox **Prevent incoming connections when on a public network** in the specific firewall settings for public networks. After doing that it started working for me as well. See screenshots attached at the end of this message.

Don't know how long this option has been there already. I'm currently working on Win 10 Pro 1709 16299.402.

---

**1. Open specific firewall settings for public networks**
[image: Open specific firewall settings for public networks]

**2. Uncheck this checkbox**
[image: Uncheck this checkbox]

Answer (score 2):

I had same issue with F-secure, DeepGuard was blocking the Docker service. My solution was:

Open F-secure client and click "**Tasks**"

[image]

Choose "**Allow a program to start**"

[image]

Choose from list "com.docker.service" and press "**Remove**"

[image]

After that **restart** Docker client and try to apply for file share.

Also very good troubleshoot guide here: [Error: A firewall is blocking file sharing between Windows and the containers](https://success.docker.com/KBase/Error%3A_A_firewall_is_blocking_file_sharing_between_Windows_and_the_containers)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with firewall not allowing me to share my C drive. I tried all listed above solutions and nothing worked for me. Then I uninstalled docker completely from my machine `Control Panel\Programs\Programs and Features  -> 
 select  Docker for Windows -> Uninstall`

 Then go to [docker website and click `Get Docker for Windows (Stable)`](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/#download-docker-for-windows)

 After that I was able to share drive C

Comment: I have literally tried everything else, only this solution worked for me. Thanks man!

Answer (score 2):

For AVG Internet Security, enabling **Internet Connection Sharing Mode** under the **Firewall settings** did the trick for me.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Using Kaspersky Internet Security you can resolve this easily if you change the `vEthernet (DockerNAT)` network adapter type to `Trusted network`.

**Settings > Protection > Firewall > Networks > vEthernet (DockerNAT) > Select "Trusted Network"**

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

In short, use the Edge version.

The Edge version of Docker for Windows since 2.1.5.0 (2019-11-04) has a new implementation of file sharing without requiring firewall modifications
https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/edge-release-notes/

"New file sharing implementation: Docker Desktop introduces a new file sharing implementation which uses gRPC, FUSE, and Hypervisor sockets instead of Samba, CIFS, and Hyper-V networking. The new implementation offers improved I/O performance. Additionally, when using the new file system:

```
Users don’t have to expose the Samba port, and therefore do not experience issues related to IT firewall or the drive-sharing policy.
There is no need to provide user credentials to Docker Desktop. File access rights are automatically enforced when accessing mounted folders through containers.
```

"

You can download the edge version: https://download.docker.com/win/edge/Docker%20Desktop%20Installer.exe

Note as of now, the edge version of 2.1.7.0 will be used for next stable release: "Note: Docker Desktop Edge 2.1.7.0 is the release candidate for the upcoming major Stable release.". So the risk of using Edge is relatively low. Or you can wait for next stable release, to avoid all these firewall issues.

Comment: I had similar issues. I updated to the stable version in january 2021 and all problems went away.

Answer (score 2):

## 25 Jan 2020

It seems, it is an issue in the old versions, I installed the last version :

```
Docker version 19.03.5, build 633a0ea
```

and it worked for me without any configuration.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This (link below) seems to be the best fix i have found so far.  It is persistant across reboots. It is best explained here:  https://gist.github.com/biggyspender/8b5b2ed9ff63de31045d41304e3915b3

The vEthernet network interface seems to be dynamically created each time the system is started, and it is created in the 'Public' group as opposed to in the 'Private' group (where it works).  The edits in one of the Docker startup scripts (called out in the link above) automate the powershell command / fix noted by David Tesar above....

I had more luck adding the function to the script as opposed to editing the script and changing 'Internal' to 'Private'.

Answer (score 1):

If non of the above works, just make sure you're not connected to a **VPN**. That's exactly what happened to me, i was connected to a VPN using Cisco AnyConnect client, also make sure you set an static DNS in the docker settings.

Comment: If you need both (VPN AnyConnect and Docker), see my comment https://stackoverflow.com/a/58406873/9064636

Answer (score 1):

I tried everything listed here and on https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/360

Nothing worked for me.

I run my dev environment on a docker container, and while on Corporate VPN (Cisco AnyConnect), I need the to mount my local drive on the container to access my project files.

Here's a docker hack that worked for me. Add `--publish 8000:8000` to your existing docker run command.

So

```
docker run -v C:/Users/kumar.joshi/KumarData:/mnt --name dev <image:latest>
```

will become

```
docker run -v C:/Users/kumar.joshi/KumarData:/mnt --name dev --publish 8000:8000 <image:latest>
```

Make sure the port is not used else you will get this error:

> Bind for 0.0.0.0:8000 failed: port is already allocated

Answer (score 0):

for those who can not solve this issue by any means, you can try this: manually map drive into the docker host:

https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/466#issuecomment-416682825

The research is here: https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/466#issuecomment-398305463

Answer (score 0):

I found it quite easy. Just go to you network connections. You can go **Control Panel/Network and Sharing.** You will find various connections. Search for Docker connection. Select which ever is default. After selecting network, go to Properties. In the properties section enable the option **Hyper-V Extensible Virtual Switch**. This will help virtual container to use network card.

Answer (score 0):

What did it for me (after several hours of trial-n-error) was changing the Subnet Mask from `255.255.255.240` to `255.255.255.0` (which should not change anything).

As part of the trial-n-error, I had done everything else listed on article, but without any success .. but this last step did it .. and reverting back to `255.255.255.240` does not break the good cycle.

*I admit, it makes no sense .. but it might be related to an internal state only being triggered by the network change.*

Anyway, if i have helped just one, then it was worth the effort.

```
Docker Desktop edge, 2.0.4.1 (34207)
```

Answer (score 0):

Enabling the option Hyper-V Extensible Virtual Switch worked for me. Other solutions have not worked for me.
I did it changing the configuration in the **HyperV Virtual Switch Manager** - DockerNAT - Extensions - Virtual Switch Extensions panel.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution! I am not sure how I solved this problem, but I think it was the following approach that did the trick.

- Open Hyper-V Manager
- Select Virtual Switch Manager
- If several Virtual Switches are called DockerNAT, rename one of them to any other name.
- Make sure DockerNAT has connection type Internal network.
- Also, make sure that any duplicates have connection type "External Network" and use an ethernet connection, not a wireless connection (in the dropdown menu).
- Press ok and close Hyper-V Manager
- Restart the computer (twice, just in case).
- Now, try to share the drive for docker in Docker For Windows.

Answer (score 0):

For me the only thing I had to do was to temporally disable the firewall in symantec endpoint protection. Share the C-drive in docker setting GUI. Come back and enable the firewall in symantec. (no powershell command etc...)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. open the windows defender firewall settings on windows.
2. open the link "windows defender firewall properties"
3. select private profile tab
4. press customize button of "protected network connections"
5. uncheck  "vEthernet (DockerNAT)"
6. go back to dockers desktop and apply the share

[Step by step instructions image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujmvi.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

My Solution:

I am using QuickHeal Antivirus and by following these steps it worked for me.

**Step #1** Go to Firewall Protection
[image: Step1]

**Step #2** Select Advance Settings
[image: Step2]

**Step #3** Find "Public" under Network Profile column and turn "File & Printer Sharing option "ON"
[image: Step3]

Answer (score 0):

The only way for me to make it work was to create a local user on my PC and use it for credentials while sharing.

More info here: https://www.mattwoodward.com/2019/05/09/docker-on-windows-10-sharing-a-drive-when-logging-in-with-a-microsoft-account/

Answer (score 0):

None of the suggestions above worked for me, but uninstalling Docker Desktop (restart PC) and reinstalling Docked finally resolved the issue.