# What to change in Norton to allow Docker to share drive D

Tags: docker, windows-10, norton

I'm using Docker on Windows10 Pro, and I'm trying to use the Docker settings UI to provide Docker with access to drive D.

When I do this I get an error ...

```
Firewall detected. A firewall is blocking file Sharing between 
Windows and the containers. See documentation for more info.
```

... with a link to: https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/#firewall-rules-for-shared-drives

I'm using Norton 360 Premier.  How and what do I need to change in Norton to allow Docker to use drive D?

Comment: You just have to disable the firewall.

Comment: Sure - but in Norton,  where/how do I inject this firewall exception?

Answer (score 13):

I'm not sure if this is optimal, but this is how I got around it:

[image: Firewall General Settings]

I then clicked the Add button and added my entry:
[image: Add Device]

`10.0.75.2` seems to be a magic address that docker uses, according to their [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/#shared-drives).

Comment: Worked for me. I added `10.0.75.0` and `10.0.75.1` and `10.0.75.2`