# Docker Windows 10 - How to run Jenkins, with bound volume on d drive without getting permission errors

Tags: docker, jenkins, windows-10

**These are the steps I have taken so far?**

1. Install Docker for windows - v0.15.0
2. Run Docker for windows > Right click - docker > settings > Shared Drives - set D drive as sharing.
3. Restart PC
4. Re-Run Docker for Windows
5. create myswitch in application
   open program - hyperv > virtual switch manager > create virtual switch > name = myvm1
6. Create docker machine switch - myvm1

   `docker-machine create -d hyperv --hyperv-virtual-switch "myswitch" myvm1`
7. Create dockar machine - default

   `$ docker-machine create --driver hyperv default`
8. Configure this - cmder - to enable access to docker commands

   `$ docker-machine env --shell cmd default
   $ @FOR /f "tokens=*" %i IN ('docker-machine env --shell cmd default') DO @%i`
9. Create Dockerized Jenkins container and bind to D drive, where permissions should be allowed

   `docker run --name myJenkins1 -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v //d/jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home jenkins/jenkins:lts`

**Error below**

`touch: Can not write to /var/jenkins_home/copy_reference_file.log. Wrong volume permissions?
cannot touch '/var/jenkins_home/copy_reference_file.log': Permission denied`

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record, I bumped into the same issue after several days running my Jenkins container without problems, suddenly it refused to start again spitting the error described in the question. After one hour investigating I tried to unshare the C: drive and sharing it again, and finally Docker Desktop told me that I had a firewall blocking the port 445 and hence blocking the sharing of files between the host machine and the virtual machine. Probably a rule added by the system administrator after a system update.

I made a quick test just disabling the firewall and the Jenkins container started again without problems. More info on this problem here: [Settings to Windows Firewall to allow Docker for Windows to share drive](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42203488/4252551)

If that does not work, maybe you changed your Windows account password. In that case you just need to reset the Docker credentials for sharing files, so Docker can access again the file system.

Comment: Unsharing C: and then re-sharing worked for me. Thanks